# How to sync animated graphics with beamer next-slide click?

Tags: animate

Using `\animategraphics` of the **animate** package, I would like to move from one image to the next by clicking on the next slide button instead of clicking on the image (as in script below).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[step]{animate}

\mode<presentation>

\title{Title}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Bio}

\begin{block}{Background}
Development assistance\\
Project management and evaluation
\animategraphics[height=5cm]{1}{image/image}{1}{2} 
\end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Is is possible to automatically to create a new slide for each image?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the JavaScript API of Adobe Reader doesn't provide an event handler which would listen to key-down events. Otherwise, it would have been used in the `animate` package.

Thus, it isn't possible to step within `\animategraphics`-generated animations using the keyboard alone. Your best bet is to use the JavaScript-free overlay feature of the `beamer` class. It produces multi-page frames in case of overlays.